# GZip Compression Not working in internet explorer 11, but working fine in Chrome & Firefox

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gzip, internet-explorer-11

Co's,

I enabled GZip compression in my Spring Boot Embedded Tomcat using CompressingFilter (https://github.com/ziplet/ziplet) and FilterRegistrationBean from Spring.

**It is working fine in Chrome & Firefox**.

- I am getting Content-Encoding = gzip in response headers
- Transferred JSON data size is reduced from 6.5MB to 1.2 MB - Great :-)

But, the same code is **NOT** working in **Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.18097.**

In Internet Explorer,

- Content-Encoding = gzip is missing in response headers
- Transferred JSON data size is still 6.5MB only.

I have pasted my headers ( IE11 ) below.
 [image: Request Header in IE11]

[image: Response Headers - IE11]

Could anyone help me to figure out this issue?

**Update:**
Please find **Chrome** Headers below.

[image]

Comment: compare the request headers to chrome and see if there are any differences.  also are you fronting tomcat with something that might be detecting IE and munging the request before forwarding it to tomcat?

Comment: @NG, no differences in request headers, I attached my chrome headers too. I am using Embed Tomcat with Spring Boot. Anyway, "munging the request before forwarding it to tomcat" is independent of browser. Then How it is working in Chrome & Firefox?

Comment: because the munging logic could do something based on user agent.  That's often how it does it.

Comment: Am not fronting my tomcat with any servers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Internet Explorer's decompression logic happens at a level below the Developer Tools, so you may not see a `Content-Encoding` in the Developer Tools. You should consider using Fiddler to see what's actually on the wire.

Comment: More explanation under  [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2012/07/23/i-dont-see-content-encoding-header-in-ie-http-debugger-f12-developer-tools)

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at the **[link](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1795907/content-encoding-gzip-in-response-header-is-missing-on-ie11)**. It was filed as an issue, but microsoft decided for whatever reason not to fix on IE11. They fixed it in the new Edge browser.

Please take a look at the comments in the link provided.