# C# AJAX serialized JSON returns not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, json, ajax, internet-explorer

When I try to return a serialized JSON value from my controller class in my application, the request body in IE returns junk. However it works just fine in Chrome or FF. This is what I see in IE's network log:

[image: IE Network Log Request BOdy]

I debugged the code, and verified that the serialized value is good. The value in the return looks like this ("output" is the value that is returned):

[image: Value before sent to IE]

When I look at the request body in Chrome, it looks exactly like it does in the IDE while debugging (send image).

I'm assuming IE doesn't like something with the Serialized JSON object, but I have no idea how to fix this. This is with IE 11, and Edge. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could it be compressed?  It so maybe see [GZip Compression Not working in internet explorer 11, but working fine in Chrome & Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34006215/3744182).

Comment: images of code are useless. Can you copy-paste them?

Comment: The point of the images is to illustrate that the output is being altered as it goes from the controller to IE. I'm not asking for help with code.

Comment: To update this, I tried disabling compression on the server. I even removed the roles altogether. Still doing the same thing.